# ¿Existe una alternativa para "memorabilia"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, significado

Acabo de leer la siguiente frase acerca de David Bowie:

> Tenemos la suerte de contar con piezas de memorabilia suyas en nuestra colección por todo el mundo.

Me ha llamado la atención el uso de la palabra *memorabilia*. Esta palabra no aparece en el diccionario (ni en el DPD, ni en el fichero general, ni en el NTLLE), por lo que parece ser importada de otro idioma. El Merriam-Webster [la define así](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/memorabilia):

> 1. Things that are remarkable and worthy of remembrance. *A wealth of early railroad memorabilia.*
> 2. Things that stir recollection or are valued or collected for their association with a particular field or interest : mementos. *Baseball
>      memorabilia.*

Entiendo que este segundo significado es el que atañe a la frase leída. Lo curioso es que según su etimología, proviene directamente del latín (plural neutro de *memorabilis*), por lo que sería una buena candidata a formar parte del DRAE en futuras revisiones.

En cuanto a su uso, es bastante reciente pero ya en el CORDE aparece una vez, más otras nueve veces en el CREA. Google arroja aproximadamente 479000 resultados buscando solamente textos en español. Un ejemplo del CREA, tomado de un artículo de 1996 del diario El Mundo, dice:

> Subasta de memorabilia de Jackie Kennedy Onassis

Aunque hay que tener cuidado, porque muchas podrían hacer referencia a un libro de la antigüedad, *Memorabilia*, escrito por [Jenofonte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenofonte) (también denominado *Memorables*).

El traductor de Google lo traduce precisamente como "cosas [memorables](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Orf971H)", aunque no tengo muy claro si el término se refiere a cada cosa memorable en sí o a la colección completa centrada en un tema particular. O incluso si realmente la palabra "memorabilia" incluye alguna sutileza que "cosas memorables" no consiga describir.

Así pues, ¿cuál es el uso que se le da actualmente a la palabra "memorabilia" en español? ¿Existe alguna alternativa al uso de esta palabra? Si no, ¿la proponemos como candidata para la próxima edición del diccionario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En español actualmente se suele decir `objetos de interés de X` o, simplemente, `objetos de X`. Si se necesita mayor precisión, `objetos relacionados con X` u `objetos personales de X`. A veces se agrega `de colección`. La mayoría no suelen ser nada memorables; creo que nuestra denominación es mejor.

La frase sobre Bowie la podrían haber escrito así:

> Tenemos la suerte de contar con objetos de interés suyos en nuestra colección por todo el mundo.

Y la de El Mundo:

> Subasta de objetos de Jackie Kennedy Onassis

Algunos ejemplos:

> - [Enorme interés en subasta de objetos de los Beatles en Argentina](http://www.prensa.com/Enorme-interes-subasta-Beatles-Argentina_0_2955454601.html) (contraparte: [*Beatles memorabilia to be auctioned in Buenos Aires*](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-15187561))
> - [Objetos del nazismo](http://www.clarin.com/sociedad/polemica-subasta-objetos-nazismo-argentino_0_Nyb8owZS-.html)
> - [Objetos de Marilyn Monroe](http://elpais.com/elpais/2016/11/14/estilo/1479142026_926045.html)
> - Objetos de Picasso: [uno](http://elpais.com/diario/2002/10/26/andalucia/1035584558_850215.html), [dos](http://www.20minutos.es/noticia/376571/0/bose/subasta/picasso/)

Personalmente, la palabra “memorabilia” (con este significado) me parece innecesaria e inexacta.

Answer (score 2):

¿Qué tal [**reliquia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vqcu08L)?

> 6. f. Objeto o prenda con valor sentimental, generalmente por haber pertenecido a una persona querida.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece óptimo que se pudiere ampliar nuestro léxico con la palabra memorabilia. Ahora, como sinónimo se me ocurren, similar a algunas opiniones ya acá escritas:

- coleccionables / los objetos coleccionables de...
- objetos de colección
- objetos de recuerdo

Espero que te sean útiles estas ideas.